# Segmentation fault in ld.so, with my build of glibc

Tags: linux, bash, shared-libraries, glibc

I have a local build of glibc.

When I run python from the command-line with it, it is successful:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64:$HOME/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$HOME/my_libc_env/usr/lib64/:$HOME/my_libc_env/usr/lib/"  $HOME/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so $HOME/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7
```

When I wrap it inside a bash script, and call it from the command line, it is also successful. (I also replaced the python symbolic link with the bash script)

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64:$HOME/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$HOME/my_libc_env/usr/lib64/:$HOME/my_libc_env/usr/lib/"  $HOME/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so $HOME/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7 "${@}"
```

However, when my IDE debugger calls the bash script, I get Segmentation Fault.
Running it with `LD_DEBUG=files,libs` yields the output below.

Any idea how to fix that?

```
      5705: 
      5705: file=libtinfo.so.5 [0];  needed by /bin/bash [0]
      5705: find library=libtinfo.so.5 [0]; searching
      5705:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5705:   trying file=/lib64/libtinfo.so.5
      5705: 
      5705: file=libtinfo.so.5 [0];  generating link map
      5705:   dynamic: 0x000000308fc1f1e0  base: 0x0000000000000000   size: 0x0000000000220260
      5705:     entry: 0x000000308fa0c840  phdr: 0x000000308fa00040  phnum:                  6
      5705: 
      5705: 
      5705: file=libdl.so.2 [0];  needed by /bin/bash [0]
      5705: find library=libdl.so.2 [0]; searching
      5705:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5705:   trying file=/lib64/libdl.so.2
      5705: 
      5705: file=libdl.so.2 [0];  generating link map
      5705:   dynamic: 0x0000003f8d802da0  base: 0x0000000000000000   size: 0x0000000000203100
      5705:     entry: 0x0000003f8d600de0  phdr: 0x0000003f8d600040  phnum:                  9
      5705: 
      5705: 
      5705: file=libc.so.6 [0];  needed by /bin/bash [0]
      5705: find library=libc.so.6 [0]; searching
      5705:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5705:   trying file=/lib64/libc.so.6
      5705: 
      5705: file=libc.so.6 [0];  generating link map
      5705:   dynamic: 0x0000003f8dd8db40  base: 0x0000000000000000   size: 0x0000000000393928
      5705:     entry: 0x0000003f8da1ee30  phdr: 0x0000003f8da00040  phnum:                 10
      5705: 
      5705: 
      5705: prelink checking: ok
      5705: 
      5705: calling init: /lib64/libc.so.6
      5705: 
      5705: 
      5705: calling init: /lib64/libdl.so.2
      5705: 
      5705: 
      5705: calling init: /lib64/libtinfo.so.5
      5705: 
      5705: 
      5705: initialize program: /bin/bash
      5705: 
      5705: 
      5705: transferring control: /bin/bash
      5705: 
      5705: 
      5705: file=libnss_files.so.2 [0];  needed by /bin/bash [0]
      5705: find library=libnss_files.so.2 [0]; searching
      5705:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5705:   trying file=/lib64/libnss_files.so.2
      5705: 
      5705: file=libnss_files.so.2 [0];  generating link map
      5705:   dynamic: 0x00007f5963ec5df8  base: 0x00007f5963cb9000   size: 0x000000000020d590
      5705:     entry: 0x00007f5963cbb1f0  phdr: 0x00007f5963cb9040  phnum:                  9
      5705: 
      5705: 
      5705: calling init: /lib64/libnss_files.so.2
      5705: 
      5705: opening file=/lib64/libnss_files.so.2 [0]; direct_opencount=1
      5705: 
      5705: 
      5705: file=libnss_nis.so.2 [0];  needed by /bin/bash [0]
      5705: find library=libnss_nis.so.2 [0]; searching
      5705:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5705:   trying file=/lib64/libnss_nis.so.2
      5705: 
      5705: file=libnss_nis.so.2 [0];  generating link map
      5705:   dynamic: 0x00007f5963cb7de0  base: 0x00007f5963aae000   size: 0x000000000020a4b8
      5705:     entry: 0x00007f5963ab0020  phdr: 0x00007f5963aae040  phnum:                  9
      5705: 
      5705: 
      5705: file=libnsl.so.1 [0];  needed by /lib64/libnss_nis.so.2 [0]
      5705: find library=libnsl.so.1 [0]; searching
      5705:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5705:   trying file=/lib64/libnsl.so.1
      5705: 
      5705: file=libnsl.so.1 [0];  generating link map
      5705:   dynamic: 0x0000003f9e015da8  base: 0x0000000000000000   size: 0x0000000000218ab0
      5705:     entry: 0x0000003f9de04070  phdr: 0x0000003f9de00040  phnum:                  9
      5705: 
      5705: 
      5705: calling init: /lib64/libnsl.so.1
      5705: 
      5705: 
      5705: calling init: /lib64/libnss_nis.so.2
      5705: 
      5705: opening file=/lib64/libnss_nis.so.2 [0]; direct_opencount=1
      5705: 
      5706: file=/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7 [0];  generating link map
      5706:   dynamic: 0x00000000006009c0  base: 0x0000000000000000   size: 0x0000000000200bf8
      5706:     entry: 0x0000000000400700  phdr: 0x0000000000400040  phnum:                  8
      5706: 
      5706: 
      5706: file=libpython2.7.so.1.0 [0];  needed by /home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7 [0]
      5706: find library=libpython2.7.so.1.0 [0]; searching
      5706:  search path=/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/../lib/tls/x86_64:/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/../lib/tls:/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/../lib/x86_64:/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/../lib      (RPATH from file /home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7)
      5706:   trying file=/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/../lib/tls/x86_64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      5706:   trying file=/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/../lib/tls/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      5706:   trying file=/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/../lib/x86_64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      5706:   trying file=/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
      5706: 
      5706: file=libpython2.7.so.1.0 [0];  generating link map
      5706:   dynamic: 0x00007fa7bcfd2c68  base: 0x00007fa7bcc37000   size: 0x00000000003fb4e0
      5706:     entry: 0x00007fa7bcc78250  phdr: 0x00007fa7bcc37040  phnum:                  5
      5706: 
      5706: 
      5706: file=libpthread.so.0 [0];  needed by /home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7 [0]
      5706: find library=libpthread.so.0 [0]; searching
      5706:  search path=/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/../lib       (RPATH from file /home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7)
      5706:   trying file=/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/../lib/libpthread.so.0
      5706:  search path=tls/x86_64:tls:x86_64::/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64/tls/x86_64:/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64/tls:/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64/x86_64:/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64/tls/x86_64:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64/tls:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64/x86_64:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64:/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64:/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls:/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64:/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/my_libc_env/usr/lib64/tls/x86_64:/my_libc_env/usr/lib64/tls:/my_libc_env/usr/lib64/x86_64:/my_libc_env/usr/lib64:/my_libc_env/usr/lib/tls/x86_64:/my_libc_env/usr/lib/tls:/my_libc_env/usr/lib/x86_64:/my_libc_env/usr/lib       (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
      5706:   trying file=tls/x86_64/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=tls/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=x86_64/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64/tls/x86_64/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64/tls/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64/x86_64/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64/tls/x86_64/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64/tls/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64/x86_64/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/my_libc_env/usr/lib64/tls/x86_64/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/my_libc_env/usr/lib64/tls/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/my_libc_env/usr/lib64/x86_64/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/my_libc_env/usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/my_libc_env/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/my_libc_env/usr/lib/tls/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/my_libc_env/usr/lib/x86_64/libpthread.so.0
      5706:   trying file=/my_libc_env/usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
      5706:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5706:   trying file=/lib64/libpthread.so.0
      5706: 
      5706: file=libpthread.so.0 [0];  generating link map
      5706:   dynamic: 0x0000003f8e017d90  base: 0x0000000000000000   size: 0x000000000021c3f0
      5706:     entry: 0x0000003f8de05e30  phdr: 0x0000003f8de00040  phnum:                  9
      5706: 
      5706: 
      5706: file=libdl.so.2 [0];  needed by /home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7 [0]
      5706: find library=libdl.so.2 [0]; searching
      5706:  search path=/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/../lib       (RPATH from file /home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7)
      5706:   trying file=/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/../lib/libdl.so.2
      5706:  search path=tls/x86_64:tls:x86_64::/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64      (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
      5706:   trying file=tls/x86_64/libdl.so.2
      5706:   trying file=tls/libdl.so.2
      5706:   trying file=x86_64/libdl.so.2
      5706:   trying file=libdl.so.2
      5706:   trying file=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64/libdl.so.2
      5706:   trying file=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64/libdl.so.2
      5706:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5706:   trying file=/lib64/libdl.so.2
      5706: 
      5706: file=libdl.so.2 [0];  generating link map
      5706:   dynamic: 0x0000003f8d802da0  base: 0x0000000000000000   size: 0x0000000000203100
      5706:     entry: 0x0000003f8d600de0  phdr: 0x0000003f8d600040  phnum:                  9
      5706: 
      5706: 
      5706: file=libutil.so.1 [0];  needed by /home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7 [0]
      5706: find library=libutil.so.1 [0]; searching
      5706:  search path=/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/../lib       (RPATH from file /home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7)
      5706:   trying file=/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/../lib/libutil.so.1
      5706:  search path=tls/x86_64:tls:x86_64::/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64      (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
      5706:   trying file=tls/x86_64/libutil.so.1
      5706:   trying file=tls/libutil.so.1
      5706:   trying file=x86_64/libutil.so.1
      5706:   trying file=libutil.so.1
      5706:   trying file=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64/libutil.so.1
      5706:   trying file=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64/libutil.so.1
      5706:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5706:   trying file=/lib64/libutil.so.1
      5706: 
      5706: file=libutil.so.1 [0];  generating link map
      5706:   dynamic: 0x0000003f9fe01e10  base: 0x0000000000000000   size: 0x0000000000202100
      5706:     entry: 0x0000003f9fc00e10  phdr: 0x0000003f9fc00040  phnum:                  9
      5706: 
      5706: 
      5706: file=libm.so.6 [0];  needed by /home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7 [0]
      5706: find library=libm.so.6 [0]; searching
      5706:  search path=/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/../lib       (RPATH from file /home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7)
      5706:   trying file=/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/../lib/libm.so.6
      5706:  search path=tls/x86_64:tls:x86_64::/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64      (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
      5706:   trying file=tls/x86_64/libm.so.6
      5706:   trying file=tls/libm.so.6
      5706:   trying file=x86_64/libm.so.6
      5706:   trying file=libm.so.6
      5706:   trying file=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64/libm.so.6
      5706:   trying file=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64/libm.so.6
      5706:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5706:   trying file=/lib64/libm.so.6
      5706: 
      5706: file=libm.so.6 [0];  generating link map
      5706:   dynamic: 0x0000003f8e882df8  base: 0x0000000000000000   size: 0x00000000002830b8
      5706:     entry: 0x0000003f8e603e70  phdr: 0x0000003f8e600040  phnum:                  9
      5706: 
      5706: 
      5706: file=libc.so.6 [0];  needed by /home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7 [0]
      5706: find library=libc.so.6 [0]; searching
      5706:  search path=/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/../lib       (RPATH from file /home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7)
      5706:   trying file=/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/../lib/libc.so.6
      5706:  search path=tls/x86_64:tls:x86_64::/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64      (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
      5706:   trying file=tls/x86_64/libc.so.6
      5706:   trying file=tls/libc.so.6
      5706:   trying file=x86_64/libc.so.6
      5706:   trying file=libc.so.6
      5706:   trying file=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64/libc.so.6
      5706:   trying file=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64/libc.so.6
      5706:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      5706:   trying file=/lib64/libc.so.6
      5706: 
      5706: file=libc.so.6 [0];  generating link map
      5706:   dynamic: 0x0000003f8dd8db40  base: 0x0000000000000000   size: 0x0000000000393928
      5706:     entry: 0x0000003f8da1ee30  phdr: 0x0000003f8da00040  phnum:                 10
      5706: 
      5706: 
      5706: calling init: /lib64/libpthread.so.0
      5706: 
      5706: 
      5706: calling init: /home/user/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
      5706: 
      5706: 
      5706: calling init: /lib64/libc.so.6
      5706: 
/home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python: line 12:  5706 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/cuda/lib64:$HOME/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$HOME/my_libc_env/usr/lib64/:$HOME/my_libc_env/usr/lib/" /home/user/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so /home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7 "${@}"
      5705: 
      5705: calling fini: /bin/bash [0]
      5705: 
      5705: 
      5705: calling fini: /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 [0]
      5705: 
      5705: 
      5705: calling fini: /lib64/libdl.so.2 [0]
      5705: 
      5705: 
      5705: calling fini: /lib64/libnss_nis.so.2 [0]
      5705: 
      5705: 
      5705: calling fini: /lib64/libnss_files.so.2 [0]
      5705: 
      5705: 
      5705: calling fini: /lib64/libnsl.so.1 [0]
      5705: 
      5705: 
      5705: calling fini: /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]
      5705: 

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell script contains:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="...:$HOME/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:..."
```

and

```
$HOME/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7
```

Your trace contains:

```
file=libpython2.7.so.1.0 [0];  needed by /home/user/anaconda2/envs/tf_011g/bin/python2.7
```

and

```
 trying file=/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libpthread.so.0
  5706:   trying file=/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libpthread.so.0
  5706:   trying file=/my_libc_env/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libpthread.so.0
```

It appears that one expansion of `$HOME` produced `/home/user`, while another expansion of `$HOME` in the same shell script produced empty string.

That seems to be exceedingly unlikely to happen, so I suspect you've actually edited one or the other, and aren't telling us the whole truth, and nothing but the truth.

Anyway, it seems possible for `$HOME` to not be set when running from within IDE, and that would certainly explain both the search path observed, and the crash (the binary ended up loading `/lib64/libpthread.so.0`, which is not compatible with the `ld-linux` you are running it with).

Comment: Great catch!  $HOME was not set by default within the IDE.
Indeed, I manually edited the file a bit to remove personal info.